# If email already exist do not enter data in table and give prompt (Already present!)

Tags: php, mysql

I had a newsletter form in php which insert the email either it already presend in database table or not, but i want if email already exists then it doesn't add a duplicate entry in database table and prompt("Already exist"). Kindly fix my code below :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Newsletter extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('stories_model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('navigation');
        $this->load->view('pages/newsletter');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
    public function register()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');

        $arr['result'] = 'confirm';
        $arr['message'] = '<ul>';


        if (strlen($email) == 0) {
            $arr['result'] = 'error';
            $arr['message'] .= '<li>Please fill the email.</li>';
        }

        if ($arr['result'] != 'error') 
        { 
            $insertcomment=$this->db->insert('newsletter_subscribers',array('email'=>$email));

            $arr['result'] = 'confirm';
            $arr['message'] = 'Successfull Added.';
        }
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
    public function cronjob()
    {
        $data['stories'] = $this->newsletter_model->get_stories($email);
        $data['emails'] = $this->newsletter_model->get_emails_subscribers();
    }

}
```

Comment: it's a simply if else contition you have to make. Did you whrite this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_where](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

```
        if ($arr['result'] != 'error') 
        { 
            if(!$this->db->get_where('newsletter_subscribers', array('email' => $email), 0, 0)) {
            $insertcomment=$this->db->insert('newsletter_subscribers',array('email'=>$email));

            $arr['result'] = 'confirm';
            $arr['message'] = 'Successful Added.';

            } else {

            $arr['result'] = 'error';
            $arr['message'] = 'Already Added.';

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Newsletter extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('stories_model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('navigation');
        $this->load->view('pages/newsletter');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
    public function register()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');

        $arr['result'] = 'confirm';
        $arr['message'] = '<ul>';


        if (strlen($email) == 0) {
            $arr['result'] = 'error';
            $arr['message'] .= '<li>Please fill the email.</li>';
        }

        if ($arr['result'] != 'error') 
        { 
            $getEmails = $this->db->get_where('newsletter_subscribers', array('email' => $email)
            $countEmails = $getEmails->num_rows();
            if($countEmails < 1)
            {
                $insertcomment=$this->db->insert('newsletter_subscribers',array('email'=>$email));
                $arr['result'] = 'confirm';
                $arr['message'] = 'Successfull Added.';
            }
            else
            {
                $arr['result'] = 'error';
                $arr['message'] = 'Email Already Exist.';
            }

        }
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
    public function cronjob()
    {
        $data['stories'] = $this->newsletter_model->get_stories($email);
        $data['emails'] = $this->newsletter_model->get_emails_subscribers();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain what you did and how it works so that both OP and others that finds this question in the future will learn something and not just blindly copy/paste code.

Comment: hey brother i've counted rows of given query which may esay to understand for new user

Comment: IS is still not Not Working

Comment: hey sumit you may echo $countEmails and then put die(); for debugging